# Finding a Hamiltonian function with or without Lagrangian

Tags: dynamical-systems, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

Is it possible to find a Hamiltonian function for a system without having the Lagrangian first?

I have the pendulum equation without damping and without sinusoidal driving force, that is

$$\frac{d^2\varphi}{dt^2}+\sin(\varphi)=\gamma$$

where the constant forcing term $\gamma$ is kept.

Introduce the generalized momentum $p=\dot{\varphi}=\frac{d\varphi}{dt}$ and the generalized coordinate $q=\varphi$.

Now, the only equation I have ever used, and seen, for forming the Hamiltonian is
$$H=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\dot{q}_i-L(q,\dot{q},t)$$

Where $L$ is the Lagrangian. Is there a way to form a Hamiltonian function from the pendulum equation without first deriving the Lagrangian? And how would one go about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamilton's equations of motion are :
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} = \dot q \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} = -\dot p$$

If you are taking $p = \dot q$, then to reproduce the equations for the pendulum, you need :
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} = p \qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} = \sin q - \gamma$$

This is solved by :
$$H = \frac{1}{2} p^2 -\cos q - \gamma q$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SolubleFish ! I hadn't thought about the equations of motion (dynamical systems are not my strong suit). Wouldn't the Hamiltonian function be $H=\frac{1}{2}p^2-\cos q-\gamma q$ for the partial derivative $\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}$ to be true? And just a follow up question, is it possible to show that $\frac{d^2\varphi}{dt^2}+\sin(\varphi)=\gamma$ is equivalent to Hamilton’s equations for the canonical variables p and q?

Comment: I edited to correct the sign error. The equation $\ddot \varphi + \sin(\varphi) = \gamma$ is a consequence of Hamilton's equations. The other way, we could have take $p = a\dot{q}$, in which case the Hamiltonian is $H = \frac{1}{2a}p^2 - a (\cos q -\gamma q)$. I don't know what kind of result we could hope for.

Comment: I don't get how we arrive at $\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}=\sin{q}-\gamma$. We know that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}=-\dot{p}$ and that $p=\dot{\varphi}$, and I don't get how we get to $-\dot{p}=\sin{q}-\gamma$ @SolubleFish

Comment: I am not sure I get what you are missing : the dynamics is fixed by the Hamiltonian function $H(\varphi,p)$.  $\dot p ,\dot \varphi$ are determined by Hamilton's equation in terms of $H$. We get $\dot \varphi = p$ and $-\dot p = \sin \varphi - \gamma$. Plugging the first in the second gives $\ddot \varphi + \sin(\varphi) = \gamma$

Comment: I'm going to sleep on it and see if it makes sense tomorrow. Thanks for the help!